# split a long string into mutltiple dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to split a long string into mutltiple dynamic divs when the height of the div gets to a certain length. Here is the code that I thought should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = longishstring.split(' ');
    $('#bookpages').append("<div id='cont'></div>");
    elem = $('#cont');
    for (i = 0; arr.length > i; i++) {
        elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
        if (elem.text().height > 475) {
            $('#bookpages').append("<div id='cont" + i + "'></div>");
            elem = $('#cont' + i);
            elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that it's reading the div height as 0 instead of the updated height. What am I missing here? If I split by length it works just fine, but that won't work for what I'm wanting  to do.

Comment: The browser only recalculates the layout of a page when a "reflow" is triggered. These are usually quite expensive computationally so certain browsers (notably Chrome) will wait until a JS method finishes executing (or there's an async call) to perform a reflow. Because of this, the div may not actually resize until your function finishes executing. See https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var l, i = 0, arr = longishstring.split(' '),
        elem = $('<div id="cont"/>').appendTo("#bookpages");
    for (l = arr.length; l > i; i++) {
        elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
        if (elem.height() > 475) {
            elem = $('<div id="#cont'+i+'"/>').appendTo('#bookpages');
            elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner way to write it. Thank you, but it still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`elem.text().height` is not going to give you the height, it will give you `undefined`.

Use:

```
elem.height()
```

Comment: The element will not have a height until AFTER it is inserted into the DOM. so what's happening in your loop is that you're still looking at value of 'elem' which is in memory, NOT THE DOM.

Comment: I can except that,but there has to be a way to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Insert the element into the DOM and use the negative-text indent trick to hide it (text-indent: -9999px try using display: block;), then take the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was being caused by the placement of the coding. For some reason if I used that code before the coding of another javascript plugin, then the height always returned as 0. By putting the code behind the other script, the divs were created. The only issue now is that although created, the divs don't seem to work with the plugin and the CSS for #bookpages is being ignored. I ended up using much of Joe Johnsons version of the script mixed with my own style.

```
    $(function() {
    var l, i = 0, arr = longishstring.split(' ');
      $("#bookpages").append('<div id="cont"></div>');
      elem = $('#cont');
      for (l = arr.length; l > i; i++) {
        elem.append(arr[i] + ' ' + elem.height());
        if (elem.height() > 200) {
          $("#bookpages").append('<div id="cont'+i+'"></div>');
          elem = $('#cont' +i);
          elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
        }
      }
    });
```

I'll have to look into why the CSS is being ignored and may eventually have to post another question in relation to this one. Thanks everyone!